# Hashing passwords before sending to server

Tags: sql, security, sockets, hash, passwords

When sending passwords via UTF-8 encoded socket transfer, is it considered to be secure if I hash the password using either MD5 or SHA-1 prior to sending out the data? Keep in mind that I plan to compare the hashed password in a SQL database. I am worried that someone could be able to sniff the hashed password in UTF-8 then decrypt the UTF-8 encoding and could obtain my hashed password which could potentially be used to match the password in my database.

Comment: Use SSL and compare the server certificate with a hash of it embedded in the program.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the client just sends the hashed password, then the hashed password *is* the "password": a sequence of bytes which the client just needs to show to be authenticated. If the attacker can sniff that then your protocol is doomed.

If the authentication protocol consists in just presenting a piece of secret data (call it a password if you wish), then the exchange should occur within a transport medium which ensures confidentiality (so that the secret data cannot be sniffed) and server authentication (so that an attacker may not mimic a server and convince a client to send him the secret data). This is what you get out of a classic SSL/TLS tunnel (a `https://` URL, in a Web context).

If you cannot establish a SSL/TLS tunnel with server authentication (i.e. the server has a certificate which the client can verify), then you may want to resort to an authentication protocol with a challenge: the server sends a sequence of random bytes (the challenge) and the client responds with a hash value computed over the concatenation of the password and the challenge. Do not try this at home! It is very difficult to do it right, especially when the attacker can intercept communications (active attacks).

A more generic answer is [password-authenticated key exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password-authenticated_key_agreement) protocols. PAKE combines a cryptographic key agreement protocol (such as Diffie-Hellman) and mutual password authentication between client and server, in a way which defeats both passive and active attackers, even with relatively weak passwords (the attacker cannot get enough data to "try" passwords without interacting with either the client or the server for each guess). Unfortunately, few PAKE algorithms have been standardized beyond mathematical description, and the area is a patent minefield.

Comment: Is there a library in C++ Qt that properly uses authentication with a challenge?

Answer (score 4):

Well, if someone can sniff hash - he can fake authorization request and send the hash he already know.

Making up secure system is not easy, you would need to do authorization using asymmetric cryptography with properly signed keys to make it secure.

At least add ~100byte random salt, and use SHA1 -  this way it would be way harder to bruteforce.

Comment: in 2017, SHA1 is no longer a cryptographic hash algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

They could brute-force your passwords if they know the hashing algorithm. The simple (and not perfectly secure) solution is to use a challenge/response instead, the server issues a random string ("nonce") to be hashed along with the password hash. This makes your app invulnerable to the kind of replay attacks you're describing.

For more information, see HTTP's [digest access authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication)

Answer (score 0):

How do you check the password on the database side?

If you store the unsalted hash of the password and just compare it to the input, then the hashed password can be sniffed and reused.

It's exactly as if you were storing the password itself in the database in plain text.

If you are afraid of sniffing, use a challenge-response protocol to authenticate, but in this case the secret will be stored in the database (and will be known to anyone who has access to the database).

Alternatively, you can send a password in plain text over a protected channel (`SSL`), but you will have to install a certificate which will most probably cost you some money (if you are using an authority from a vendor-provided list, i. e. one your customers' browsers won't complain about)

Answer (score 0):

Hm, if you are talking about 'proper' hashing, that means that it will 'encrypt' your password so it won't be decrypt-able, because hashing is one way function, and to decrypt it - it till take some time, and some kind of great [CPU power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute_force_attack).

If you are concerned at password sniffers, you can take it to the next level - use PRIVATE/PUBLIC key encryption.  Server should send a challenge to the client (public key for encryption), client encrypts with it, and only server know how to decrypt it.  For same amount of bits, it offers more protection - ie. more muscle is needed to brute force crack it.

Check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) out.